# Indeterminate Form for Partial Derivative of Flow Variables

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics, potential-theory

The following is a paraphrased version of the derivation within John D. Anderson's *Fundamentals of Aerodynamics*'s section on the Method of Characteristics:

The exact governing equation for two-dimensional supersonic, steady, and inviscid flow is as follows:
\begin{equation}
    \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \phi_x \right)^2 \right] \phi_{xx} + \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{a^2} \left( \phi_y \right)^2 \right] \phi_{yy} = \frac{2}{a^2} \phi_x \phi_y \phi_{xy}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is the [Speed of Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound), $\phi$ is the [Velocity Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_potential), and subscripts represent partial derivatives with respect to the subscript variable.
Since $ \phi_x \equiv u $ and $ \phi_y \equiv v $, the $x$- and $y$-components of the velocity field $\vec{u} = \langle u, v \rangle$, Eq. 1 can be rewritten as the following:
\begin{equation}
    \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] \phi_{xx} + \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right] \phi_{yy} = \frac{2uv}{a^2} \phi_{xy}
\end{equation}
By expanding the exact differentials for $ \phi_x $ and $ \phi_y $ as functions of $x$ and $y$, i.e. $ \phi_x = f(x, y) $, we can obtain the following:
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d} \phi_x = \mathrm{d}u = \phi_{xx} \, \mathrm{d}x + \phi_{xy} \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d} \phi_y = \mathrm{d}v = \phi_{yy} \, \mathrm{d}y + \phi_{xy} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Therefore, Eqs. (2)-(4) can be consolidated as:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 - u^2/a^2 & 1 - v^2/a^2 & - 2uv/a^2 \\
        \mathrm{d}x & 0 & \mathrm{d}y \\
        0 & \mathrm{d}y & \mathrm{d}x
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phi_{xx} \\ \phi_{yy} \\ \phi_{xy}
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\ \mathrm{d}u \\ \mathrm{d}v
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Through the use of [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), we can obtain a solution for $\phi_{xy}$:
\begin{equation}
    \phi_{xy} = \frac{ \left| \begin{matrix}
        1 - u^2/a^2 & 1 - v^2/a^2 & 0 \\
        \mathrm{d}x & 0 & \mathrm{d}u \\
        0 & \mathrm{d}y & \mathrm{d}v \end{matrix} \right| }
    { \left| \begin{matrix}
        1 - u^2/a^2 & 1 - v^2/a^2 & - 2uv/a^2 \\
        \mathrm{d}x & 0 & \mathrm{d}y \\
        0 & \mathrm{d}y & \mathrm{d}x \end{matrix} \right|} = \frac{N}{D}
\end{equation}
Evaluating the numerator and denominator determinants:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        N & = \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] \left| \begin{matrix} 0 & \mathrm{d}u \\ \mathrm{d}y & \mathrm{d}v \end{matrix} \right| - \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right] \left| \begin{matrix} \mathrm{d}x & \mathrm{d}u \\ 0 & \mathrm{d}v \end{matrix} \right| \\
        & = - \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}u \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] + \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}v \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right]
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        D & = \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] \left| \begin{matrix} 0 & \mathrm{d}y \\ \mathrm{d}y & \mathrm{d}x \end{matrix} \right| - \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right] \left| \begin{matrix} \mathrm{d}x & \mathrm{d}y \\ 0 & \mathrm{d}x \end{matrix} \right| \\
        & \quad + \left[- \frac{2uv}{a^2} \right] \left| \begin{matrix} \mathrm{d}x & 0 \\ 0 & \mathrm{d}y \end{matrix} \right| \\
        & = - \mathrm{d}y^2 \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] + \mathrm{d}x^2 \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right] - \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y \left[ \frac{2uv}{a^2} \right]
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \phi_{xy} = \frac{- \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}u \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] + \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}v \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right]}{- \mathrm{d}y^2 \left[ 1 - \frac{u^2}{a^2} \right] + \mathrm{d}x^2 \left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{a^2} \right] - \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y \left[ \frac{2uv}{a^2} \right]}
\end{equation}
One can see that for certain values of $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$, $\phi_{xy}$  can be indeterminate.

My question: **What would an indeterminate form in the derivative of a flow variable mean physically? As far as I am aware, this is not representative of a [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave).**

Comment: This notation seems pretty much meaningless to me. Do you wedge multiply differentials when you expand? Do you consider quadratic differentials? And how should dividing result in a function?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I assume you are talking about Eqs. (3) and (4) in the above. Here's what I (and I assume Anderson), did. Considering any function $f = f(x, y)$, then:
$$ \mathrm{d} f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) \mathrm{d} x + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d} y $$
We apply this same logic to $\phi_x = g(x, y)$ and $\phi_y = h(x, y)$, noting that $\phi_x \equiv u$ and $\phi_y \equiv v$. I didn't do any wedge multiplication, just the exact differential.

If this is not what you are referring to, please clarify and I'd be happy to add more information.

Comment: I have never previously used a wedge product, and have never previously heard of a quadratic differential. I should also note that I am using the notation: $$\phi_x = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \quad \phi_y = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}, \quad \phi_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}$$
$$ \phi_{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \, \partial y}, \quad \phi_{yy} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} $$
If you would like me to switch the post above to use a different notation for clarity, let me know.

Comment: This stuff is all fine. It’s when you expand the determinants that I have issues.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I have added more details to the section about the determinants. Let me know if that works. I'm not really sure why the brackets in the denominator of $\phi_{xy}$ are smaller but oh well.